# Is disposing a SqlCeDataReader a good idea?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, windows-ce, .net-1.0, sqlcedatareader

In trying to track down the cause of a Null Reference Exception which occurs only in certain situations, I came across this code:

```
SqlCeDataReader IdValsReader = IdValsCMD.ExecuteReader();
if ((IdValsReader.Read()) && (!IdValsReader.IsDBNull(0)))
{
    return string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};", 
        IdValsReader.GetValue(DESCRIPTION_INDEX),
        . . .
}
IdValsReader.Close();
```

...and wonder if I should add this line following the IdValsReader.Close():

```
IdValsReader.Dispose();
```

I did do so, but it seems to make no difference; should I leave it in or strip it out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From MSDN: [The Dispose method] Releases the resources used by the DbDataReader and calls Close.

So it seems sensible to call dispose once you're finished with the reader. Better still, wrap it all in a Using block and forget all about it.

Comment: `using (SqlCeDataReader IdValsReader = IdValsCMD.ExecuteReader()) { // code }`

Comment: Let me point out that just because MSDN says, does not make it so. Case in point: Microsoft Access OLEDB connections will **NOT** close.

Comment: Decompile the code if you don't trust MSDN. I'm not sure it's worth worrying about.